# Add multiple markers to Leaflet maps using geocoding from a file

Tags: leaflet, geocoding, markers

Can anybody get me with how to add multiple markers to a leaflet map using geocoding ? There are two parts which I wish to implement.

First part is that can I place markers on the map based on the address of each marker instead of latitude and longitude in the data file which is in .json format?

The next part is, once the address is placed on the map using geocoding, can I retrieve the latitude and longitude of the markers using reverse geocoding and store in a file?

Kindly help me with these queries.

Comment: Have you experimented with any of the Leaflet geocoding plugins?

Comment: @IvanSanchez I tried to look at those plugins but I didn't get anything to load a marker based on the address, as all the plugins were providing a search option using different services like google,bing,etc. or using a click on the map.

Comment: [Look again](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#geocoding). Some of those plugins have a UI to allow the user to search for an address, and some have functions to allow developers to send a string and get a lat-long back.

Comment: @IvanSanchez, I looked at the plugins mentioned in the Geocoding section. All of them have the search feature to add a marker. Which one allows to send a string back, Can you name that plugin ?

Comment: [Leaflet GeoSearch](https://github.com/smeijer/L.GeoSearch) (see bottom of README.md) and [Leaflet Control Geocoder](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-control-geocoder#methods-1) (don't add it to the map and call `geocode()`), for example.